What is a condition on accessibility relation corresponding to ◊□(A→B)→(◊□A→◊□B)?
Recently, I am struggling with finding specific semantic conditions on frames in which the following axiom holds (the analogue of the distribution axiom for ◊□ instead of □):
◊□(A→B)→(◊□A→◊□B)
I know that this schema is derivable in S5 and S4.2, but not in S4; what I'm trying to do is to find out is what is possibly the weakest logic that validates it.
I did some digging, but I haven't found any useful procedure for coming up with semantic analogues (first- or second-order) to axioms which cannot be put in the general form required by Lemmon-Scott theorem. I'd deeply appreciate any help with this question, even just pointing the relevant literature that might be of help, as I am not a mathematician myself.

Welcome to Philosophy StackExchange! Be sure to check out the FAQ. :D

Do you want to find the reflexive + transitive frames (i.e., S4 frames) which also validate your axiom? Or do you want to find all the frames--not necessarily reflexive or transitive--which validate your axiom?

In general, I want to find all such frames (though I am specifically interested in reflexive, but not transitive ones).

To be a bit more specific: I found that the axiom holds also in all euclidean frames (K5-frames). My inquiry is about finding out, whether it is possible to have it without having either transitivity or euclideanness; so far, I know that it holds in S4.2 and K5 frames (that is - either reflexive, transitive and convergent or just euclidean).

I agree that the S4 frames that validate your axiom are the convergent S4 frames. No idea about non-S4 frames. It should be doable, but personally I don't have enough intuition for nontransitive frames to figure out it without getting out a piece of paper.

I can offer a few observations, but not a full answer without a great deal more thought. The formula you give:
Q1. ◇□(A → B)  →  (◇□A → ◇□B) 

is logically equivalent to:
Q2. (◇□(A → B) ∧ ◇□A) → ◇□B 

Hence, it is sufficient to derive the distributivity of conjunction over ◇□:
Q3. (◇□p ∧ ◇□q) → ◇□(p ∧ q)

Since if we have that, then we can substitute A → B for p and A for q to get:
Q4. (◇□(A → B) ∧ ◇□A) → ◇□((A → B) ∧ A)

This can be combined with the following which is valid in K
Q5. ◇□((A → B) ∧ A) → ◇□B

And hence Q2 follows from Q4 and Q5 by hypothetical syllogism.
So, how can we derive Q3? Here's one way to do it, assuming axioms K, 4 and G (also called .2) ◇□A → □◇A
Q6. ◇□p ∧ ◇□q                    Assumption
Q7. ◇□p                           Q6, ∧-E
Q8. ◇□□p                          Q7, 4 
Q9. □◇□p                          Q8, G 
Q10. ◇□q                          Q6, ∧-E
Q11. ◇□□q                         Q7, 4 
Q12. □◇□p ∧ ◇□□q                  Q9, Q11, ∧-I
Q13. ◇(◇□p ∧ □□q)                 Q12, provable in K 
Q14. ◇◇(□p ∧ □q)                  Q13, provable in K
Q15. ◇(□p ∧ □q)                   Q14, 4
Q16. ◇□(p ∧ q)                    Q15, K
Q17. (◇□p ∧ ◇□q) → ◇□(p ∧ q)      Q6, Q16, CP  

Note that this doesn't use axiom T, so we don't need S4.2. The axioms 4 and G correspond to the frame conditions of transitivity and convergence.
On the other hand, S4.1 is not sufficient to derive Q1. There is a countermodel when we have a base world w having two accessible worlds u and v, with A true at u, A false at w and v, and B false at all three.
You say in the comments you are interested in systems that include reflexivity but not transitivity. I struggle to see how that is possible, though I have not investigated further.
A catalog of modal logics that I find useful is this document. It may be of help, though I daresay you know this stuff already.
